# Как перезагрузить таблицу DataTables при выполнении функции?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как перезагрузить таблицу DataTables при выполнении функции?
Функция:

```
function changeStatus(id, st){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/dcm/list_instructors.php?action=status&id=' + id + '&st=' + st,
    });    
}
```

таблица:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($("#status"));
    var table = $('#instructors').DataTable({
        "ajax": "/dcm/list_instructors.php?data=json",
        "columns": [
            {"data": "Actions"},
            {"data": "ID"},
            {"data": "Name"},
            {"data": "Address"},
            {"data": "Homephone"},
            {"data": "Workphone"},
            {"data": "Cellphone"},
            {"data": "Status"}
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с версии 1.10.0 вот так ([документация](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())):

```
function changeStatus(id, st) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/dcm/list_instructors.php?action=status&id=' + id + '&st=' + st,
    }).done(function() {
        table.DataTable().ajax.reload();
    });
}
```

На основе ответа на вопрос: "[How to reload/refresh jQuery dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24254416/2486051)".